# How to inspect pseudo elements using Internet Explorer 11 developer tools

Tags: css, pseudo-element

I need write rules for pseudo elements, but It seems IE11 browser is not showing ::after and ::before pseudo elements in its developer tools despite them being rendered on the page.

Is there way to edit them directly in browser, as it is possible on Chrome?

Comment: The pseudo elements just appear in the CSS column, unlike Chrome; you don't actually need to click on `::before` in the HTML.

Answer (score 7):

All styles in Internet Explorer appear in the **styles** tab on the right.

The html markup for pseudo elements is **not displayed within the DOM inspector** like other popular browsers.

[image]